# Apache reverse proxy - File does not exist

Tags: apache, proxy, sonarqube, reverse-proxy, sonarqube-ops

I have to configure an Apache web server as reverse proxy for my Sonarqube. The web server is listening on port **8888** and I enforce the Sonarqube to use only the **127.0.0.1** (sonar.properties):

```
sonar.web.host=127.0.0.1
```

and I have the following reverse settings (httpd.conf):

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<VirtualHost *:8888>
    ProxyPass /sonar http://127.0.0.1:9000/
    ProxyPassReverse /sonar http://127.0.0.1:9000/
</VirtualHost>
```

By accessing the URL **http://10.130.210.80:8888/sonar** the opening page from Sonarqube is displayed but without any CSS style and without images. The Apache error.log tells me the following:

```
[Wed Oct 26 13:07:06 2016] [error] [client 10.130.211.88] File does not exist: /home/www/indian/htdocs/css, referer: http://10.130.210.80:8888/sonar
[Wed Oct 26 13:07:06 2016] [error] [client 10.130.211.88] File does not exist: /home/www/indian/htdocs/js, referer: http://10.130.210.80:8888/sonar
[Wed Oct 26 13:07:06 2016] [error] [client 10.130.211.88] File does not exist: /home/www/indian/htdocs/js, referer: http://10.130.210.80:8888/sonar
[Wed Oct 26 13:07:06 2016] [error] [client 10.130.211.88] File does not exist: /home/www/indian/htdocs/js, referer: http://10.130.210.80:8888/sonar
[Wed Oct 26 13:07:06 2016] [error] [client 10.130.211.88] File does not exist: /home/www/indian/htdocs/js, referer: http://10.130.210.80:8888/sonar
[Wed Oct 26 13:07:06 2016] [error] [client 10.130.211.88] File does not exist: /home/www/indian/htdocs/images, referer: http://10.130.210.80:8888/sonar
[Wed Oct 26 13:07:06 2016] [error] [client 10.130.211.88] File does not exist: /home/www/indian/htdocs/js, referer: http://10.130.210.80:8888/sonar
[Wed Oct 26 13:07:06 2016] [error] [client 10.130.211.88] File does not exist: /home/www/indian/htdocs/images, referer: http://10.130.210.80:8888/sonar
[Wed Oct 26 13:07:06 2016] [error] [client 10.130.211.88] File does not exist: /home/www/indian/htdocs/js, referer: http://10.130.210.80:8888/sonar
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution. First, I set a context for the Sonarqube:

```
sonar.web.context=/sonarqube
```

Second, for Apache I set the **Servername** and I set the proxy pass to the Sonarqube's context:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<VirtualHost *:8888>
  ServerName 10.130.210.80:8888
  ProxyPass /sonarqube http://127.0.0.1:9000/sonarqube
  ProxyPassReverse /sonarqube http://127.0.0.1:9000/sonarqube
</VirtualHost>
```

and "Tadaaa", works!

Comment: I am running sonar on the docker. My apache (service on centOS) can't find the files.
`AH00128: File does not exist: GET /sonarqube/js/main.m.c5b6e957.js`
What do I need to configure?